# Vostro 3560 sound is not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: upgrade, sound, 13.04, dell-vostro

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 the sound is not working anymore, in Ubuntu 12.10 worked fine.

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=70f651a82676b9aab7fef8a8c51b02c5efb9e729

```
# aplay -l
aplay: device_list:252: no soundcards found...
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ;) ?

Answer (score 1):

I've put this:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-vostro-3560
```

In the end of "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf"

And my sound is working again :)

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CONEXANT Analog [CONEXANT Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah,

I get the same after upgrade to 13.04 on an ASUS zenbook UX32A:

```
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:252: no soundcards found...
```

Comment: Your "answer" doesn't seam to be an answer. If you want to comment on the problem you can use the "comment" function.

Comment: The question is: How to do the sound works again?